# Best way of performing a db load - oracle

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I want to read an entire schema in an oracle database and copy it to an in memory database (just once - at startup). This schema has about 300 tables and overall 4GB of information.
I do this load using jdbc connections.

Obviously, I want all this memory consistent, so I use read only mode.

I am looking for the fastest way to this.

One way: if I use only one connection and go at every table one by one. Psuedo code:

```
conn = getConnection();
conn.setReadOnly(true);
for(String table:allTables){
 ps = conn.prepareStatement(String.format("select * from %s", table));
 ps.execute();
 rs = ps.getResultSet();
 analyze(rs);
 rs.close();
 ps.close();
}
```

The problem here is that I am not using the database's computational power fully - so I could parallelize the above - the question is how:

1. Each connection loads a single table - this is quite easy to implement, but might create a lot of connections and become unfair, since some tables have millions of records and others mere dozens.
2. Each connections (lets say we have n connections) reads a part of each table - that is, a typical connection, indexed as i, reads 1/n of each table like so: "where rownum>count*i/n and rownum < count*(i+1)/n" count being number of records in the table.
3. The same as 2 only using mod function - "where mod(rownum,n)=i"

The approach that seems to be fastest right now is 2 - and it becomes slighly faster if I add in a threshold - so that small tables are just loaded as a whole.

Question: My question is - based on the inner working of oracle - How can I imporove the loading time of the tables?

(I mean on the one hand it seems logical that oracle would like the selects in method 1 - there is little parsing, and it minimizes number of commands processed - but it requires a lot of connections and in case of a really big one table, it would lose its efficiency.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm surprised option 2 is fast, should get slower and slower for large tables. You do have an order_by in those queries, right? (Option 3, if you can get it to work, would full-scan the tables n times.)

Comment: No. it's basically "select * from t" with a where clause only to divide the work.

Comment: Then before you do anything else, _test the data you loaded_. Without a strict ordering, rownum filters won't work. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Yeah, I know. I perform a self sub-select.
"select * from (select a,b,c,rownum as rn from t) where mod(rn,n)=i".
But the issue isn't the syntax, it is which method is optimal - that's why I avoided all the small details.

Comment: It's not a _small detail_. Really, test your data. There is nothing that guarantees that you'll extract all rows from the table with that scheme. You **need** an order_by that results in a **unique** ordering of all rows for that to work. Please read the article I linked. Comparing the performance of stuff that doesn't deliver the right data is meaningless.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what I wrote - since all my connections are read only set on the same scn.

Comment: That's not the point. Please read that article. A query without an order_by that has full ordering is not guaranteed to return the rows in the same order every time it's executed. Your approaches (2 and 3) rely on getting the same order each time to partition the data. Without a sort that uniquely sorts all rows, your options 2 and 3 are not guaranteed to return all the data.

Comment: ok. thank you. I will read the full article